# PHP Array removing the duplicate key value and displaying only one

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 78
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_user_added_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 76
            [post_id] => 8
            [post_user_added_id] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 78
            [post_id] => 9
            [post_user_added_id] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 76
            [post_id] => 9
            [post_user_added_id] => 15
        )

     [4] => Array
         (
             [user_id] => 77
             [post_id] => 9
             [post_user_added_id] => 15
         )

)
```

The idea here is that when there is a duplicate user_id, it will just display only one? This is the expected result:

```
 Array
 (
      [2] => Array
          (
             [user_id] => 78
             [post_id] => 9
             [post_user_added_id] => 12
           )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 76
                [post_id] => 9
                [post_user_added_id] => 15
            )

         [4] => Array
             (
                 [user_id] => 77
                 [post_id] => 9
                 [post_user_added_id] => 15
             )

    )
```

The reason why [2] key instead of [0] key or [1] key instead of [3] is displayed because I want to get the bottom key of the duplicate key. It's kinda hard to explain but I hope you understood the scenario or the output that I expected.

Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? - Please post your code and make clear with which point exactly you've hit the road-block.

Comment: I didn't try anything since I really don't know the logic on performing my expected output.

Comment: This website is for programmers, so please see the FAQ which questions to ask here.

Comment: Have you considered moving your arrays into a database?

Comment: I'm a programmer, that's why I came up with that PHP array values. I'm just asking how to remove duplicate values on an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) 
{
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($k != $key && $v['user_id'] == $value['user_id'])
        {
             unset($arr[$k]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: The previous one that you left was working perfectly! no need to array_reverse() it since I want to get the bottom key of the duplicate key value. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$array = Array (
        "0" => Array (
                "user_id" => 78,
                "post_id" => 3,
                "post_user_added_id" => 2 
        ),

        "1" => Array (
                "user_id" => 76,
                "post_id" => 8,
                "post_user_added_id" => 16 
        ),

        "2" => Array (
                "user_id" => 78,
                "post_id" => 9,
                "post_user_added_id" => 12 
        ),

        "3" => Array (
                "user_id" => 76,
                "post_id" => 9,
                "post_user_added_id" => 15 
        ),

        "4" => Array (
                "user_id" => 77,
                "post_id" => 9,
                "post_user_added_id" => 15 
        ) 
);
$keys = array ();

// Get Position
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $keys [$value ['user_id']] = $key;
}

// Remove Duplicate
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    if (! in_array ( $key, $keys )) {
        unset ( $array [$key] );
    }
}
var_dump ( $array );
```

Output

```
array
  2 => 
    array
      'user_id' => int 78
      'post_id' => int 9
      'post_user_added_id' => int 12
  3 => 
    array
      'user_id' => int 76
      'post_id' => int 9
      'post_user_added_id' => int 15
  4 => 
    array
      'user_id' => int 77
      'post_id' => int 9
      'post_user_added_id' => int 15
```

Comment: You might need to array_reverse the initial array, since that is not the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop to overwrite the user_id. I think something like this should work

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    $new[$value['user_id']] = $value;
}
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me, for cleaning the following:

```
$arr = array(

    array("ID"=>"234"),
    array("ID"=>"235"),
    array("ID"=>"236"),
    array("ID"=>"236"),
    array("ID"=>"234"),
    );
```

Code:

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($arr) ; $i++) {

    $distinct_id = $arr[$i]["ID"]; // this is the ID for which we want to eliminate the duplicates
    $position = $i; // position of that array (so we ignore it)
    $unset_arr = array(); // these duplicate entries will be removed

    // Collect list of duplicates to remove
    for ($y=0; $y <count($arr) ; $y++) {

        // Skip the position of the array that we're checking (we want to remove duplicate not the original)
        if($y == $position)
            continue;

        // If found remove and reset keys
        if($arr[$y]["ID"] == $distinct_id) {
            $unset_arr[] = $y;
        }

    }

    // Remove IDs collected in the loop above
    foreach ($unset_arr as $k) {
        unset($arr[$k]);
    }

    // Reset keys
    $arr = array_values($arr);

}
```

(reverse the array if you want to remove newer duplicates instead of older ones)